# H2 database, is there any way to reload past data?

Tags: spring-boot, h2, in-memory

Is there any way to reload past data after server down?

I thought that I have to save data as file type, so I typed url added ':file:' also I could find a database file (databasename.mv.db). But every time I reconnect, the file was overwritten. If someone knows how to deal with it, please tell me.

Comment: Are you running an H2 server and then connecting to it? What JDBC connection string are you using for the server, and what connection string are you using in the clients?

Comment: I'm using spring boot on server side and create some data (calling server side script to create 20 random data for test) and search those through H2 console. Both side's connection string is 'jdbc:h2:file:~/data/DBTest'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way I like to do this during the initial development phase / for loading test data into the application is to store the data in a CSV file and simply load it into H2 when the spring-boot application starts up using the ContextRefreshedEvent like below:

```
@Component
public class RootVerbLoader implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

private static final int SOURCE_LANGUAGE = 1;
private static final int TARGET_LANGUAGE = 2;
private RootVerbRepository repo;

@Autowired
public void setRepo(RootVerbRepository repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
}

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent arg0) {

    loadDataFromCSV("classpath:hanasu.csv", "to speak", "はなす");
    loadDataFromCSV("classpath:iku.csv", "to go", "いく");
    loadDataFromCSV("classpath:iu.csv", "to say", "いう");
    loadDataFromCSV("classpath:kaku.csv", "to write", "かく");
    loadDataFromCSV("classpath:kasegu.csv", "to earn", "かせぐ");
    loadDataFromCSV("classpath:kuru.csv", "to come", "くる");
    loadDataFromCSV("classpath:matsu.csv", "to wait", "まつ");
    loadDataFromCSV("classpath:miru.csv", "to look", "みる");
    loadDataFromCSV("classpath:naru.csv", "to become", "なる");
    loadDataFromCSV("classpath:nomu.csv", "to drink", "のむ");
    loadDataFromCSV("classpath:shinu.csv", "to die", "しぬ");
    loadDataFromCSV("classpath:suru.csv", "to do", "する");
    loadDataFromCSV("classpath:yobu.csv", "to call", "よぶ");
}

private void loadDataFromCSV(String filename, String source, String target) {

    Set<TranslationPair> conjugations = new HashSet<>();

    try {

        ResultSet rs = new Csv().read(filename, null, null);
        int i = 1;
        while (rs.next()) {
            conjugations.add(
                new TranslationPair(
                    rs.getString(SOURCE_LANGUAGE),
                    rs.getString(TARGET_LANGUAGE),
                    i
                )
            );
            i++;
        }

        rs.close();

    } catch(SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }

    repo.save(new RootVerb(source, target, conjugations));
}
```

}

The code for writing out data out to a CSV file is also incredibly simple:

```
SimpleResultSet rs = new SimpleResultSet();
rs.addColumn("NAME", Types.VARCHAR, 255, 0);
rs.addColumn("EMAIL", Types.VARCHAR, 255, 0);
rs.addRow("Bob Meier", "bob.meier@abcde.abc");
rs.addRow("John Jones", "john.jones@abcde.abc");
new Csv().write("data/test.csv", rs, null);
```

I find this provides a really quick way to prototype data structures / table schema without having to write any sql scripts or do much work at all really. It's really fast to get started.

Comment: Thank you for your helping :)

Comment: You're welcome. I was pretty pleased to discover h2 had this functionality and how easy it was to implement, so more than happy to share the knowledge. If this answer solved your problem please mark it as the accepted answer, so the community knows :)